# Django management.call_command throws 'Bad File Descriptor'

Tags: python, django

I created a new management command called `report.py`.

My question comes that when I run the command on the prompt like this `python manage.py report`, the report works perfectly fine.

However when I call `management.call_command('report')`, it will always throw and `ERRNO9 Bad file descriptor` that points to a model. If I need to be more specific please just say so, it's my first post ever.

Alright Ill edit this a bit more, the call is in my views like this

views.py

```
management.call_command('inventory_report', **options)
```

Specifically the erno9 points to this

report.py

```
user = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

the username is part of the objects I pass to the report itself in the options kwargs.

Comment: More specific would help - can you get a traceback of the error message?

Comment: Have you tried passing `interactive=False` to the `call_command` call?

Comment: Yea when I do that it throws an unhandled exception error.